# COLUMN STORE INDEX vs CLUSTERED INDEX..Which one to use?

Tags: sql, indexing, olap-cube, sql-server-2014

I’m trying to evaluate which type of indexes to use on our tables in the SQL Server 2014 data mart, which we are using to power our OLAP cube in SSAS. I have read the documentation on MSDN and still a bit unclear which is the right strategy for our use case with the ultimate goal of speeding up the queries on SQL Server that the cube issues when people browse the cube.

I have the tables related to each other as shown in the following snow flake dimensional model. The majority of the calculations that we are going to do in the cube, is COUNT DISTINCT of the users (UserInfoKey) based on different combination of dimensions (both filters and pivots). Keeping that in mind, what would the SQL experts suggest I do in terms of creating indexes on the tables?. I have the option of creating COLUMN STORE INDEXES on all my tables (partitioned by the HASH of primary keys) or create the regular primary keys (clustered indexes) on all my tables. Which one is better for my scenario? From my understanding the cube will be doing a lot of joins and groupby’s under the covers based on the dimensions selected by the user.

[image]

I tried both versions with some sample data and the performance isn’t that different in both cases. Now before I do the same experiment with real data (it’s going to take a lot of time to produce the real data and load it into our data mart), I wanted to check with the experts about their suggestions.

We are also evaluating if we should use PDW( Parallel Datawarehouse) as our data mart instead of vanilla SQL Server 2014.

Just to give an idea on the scale of data we are dealing with

The 2 largest tables are

1. ActivityData fact table : 784+ million rows
2. DimUserInfo dimension table: 30 + million rows

Any help or pointers are appreciated

Comment: So is the cube ROLAP, MOLAP, HOLAP?

Comment: I'm using the default setting which I believe is MOLAP.

Comment: "...with the ultimate goal of speeding up the queries on SQL Server that the cube issues when people browse the cube..." 
AFAIK, the cube issues no queries against the SQL Server (DWH?) when browsing in a MOLAP situation - only when processing. You might find something useful here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966527.aspx